# How do i crop a contourn?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm writing a code that detects parakeets eyes. Currently, I'm using a already written code that i found on youtube. It's working great with the pictures that i have, but i don't know how to display a colored version of the selected area.

The results: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RlfG.jpg)

I've tried using masks and use cv2.drawcontourns to repeat the already drawn contour on them. It worked, but i couldn't make the mask overlap the original image and crop. I think it is because the contour wasn't filled, but i don't know for sure and i don't know if a filled contour won't mess up with the rest of the code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

def nothing(x):
pass

# Load an image
img = cv2.imread('papagaio.png')

# Resize The image
if img.shape[1] > 600:
img = imutils.resize(img, width=600)

# Create a window
cv2.namedWindow('Treshed')

# create trackbars for treshold change
cv2.createTrackbar('Treshold','Treshed',0,255,nothing)


while(1):

# Clone original image to not overlap drawings
clone = img.copy()

# Convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(clone, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# get current positions of four trackbars
r = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Treshold','Treshed')

# Thresholding the gray image
ret,gray_threshed = cv2.threshold(gray,r,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Blur an image
bilateral_filtered_image = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray_threshed, 5, 175, 175)

# Detect edges
edge_detected_image = cv2.Canny(bilateral_filtered_image, 75, 200)

# Find contours
contours, _= cv2.findContours(edge_detected_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contour_list = []
for contour in contours:
    # approximte for circles
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour,0.01*cv2.arcLength(contour,True),True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if ((len(approx) > 8) & (area > 30) ):
        contour_list.append(contour)

# Draw contours on the original image
cv2.drawContours(clone, contour_list, -1, (255,0,0), 2)  


# there is an outer boundary and inner boundary for each eadge, so contours double
print('Number of found circles: {}'.format(int(len(contour_list)/2)))

#Displaying the results     
cv2.imshow('Objects Detected', clone)
cv2.imshow("Treshed", gray_threshed)


# ESC to break
k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
if k == 27:
    break

# close all open windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers. And please...no screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said, you can create mask and then apply it on the RGB image. Here's some way to do it:

```
mask = np.zeros( (clone.shape[0], clone.shape[1]), np.uint8) #create single channel mask
for contour in contours:
    cv.fillPoly(mask, pts=[contour], color=(255)) #cv.drawContours with thickness parameter = -1 should also work
cv.bitwise_and(clone, clone, mask)
```

Comment: The mask creation with filled contourn worked, but i only got a white contourn on a black background. I think this is a start! What do you think i can do now?

Comment: Already got it! i simply created another mask and overlaped them. Thank you!